# Adding default constraint to column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have added a default constraint to column(department_id), and then deleted it, after that again I try to add default constraint to same column, I could not understand why am I getting this error after deleting that, could any one help me, I am new to sql...

Error is:

> Msg 1781, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column already has a DEFAULT bound
>   to it. Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 Could not create
>   constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: Can you please post the DDL of the table, DDL of the constraint that you added and the query that you used to drop the constraint? You are using SQL Server right?

Comment: alter table employee
drop CONSTRAINT DF_employee_department_id @alok gupta

Comment: Generate the script for the table. Possible there is already a default constraint.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server management studio, then can you please right click the table and generate Create table statement and post it here? As per the error mentioned above, it says that column already has default constraint, we will be able to see it in DDL of table.

Comment: ok i have checked constraint  using 
EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_helpconstraint] 'employee'
GO statement,  its showing the default constraint which i was deleted earlier,in constraint it doesn't show to me after refreshing it that's y  i thought it has been deleted,...but it doesnt..my prbolem gets sloved thank you for support @alok

Comment: thank you for help @FLICKER

Comment: can you please tell me that how to add check constraint to date-time column,in that year should be greater than 2000. i have used condition like this DateOfJoin(YY)>2000, but am getting error @AlokGupta

Comment: what is the statement you are using and please post the error too

Comment: am using the expression this EmpDateofJoin(YY)>2000 am getting the error like this "Error validating 'CK_employee_EmpDateofJoin'. Do you want to edit the constraint?". EmpDateofJoin datatype is datetime and my target is  should not allow the EmpDateofJoin year is greater  than 2000 because company is established after that..@AlokGupta

Answer (score 1):

Check for the existing constraints of that table using system `sp`.

`EXECUTE sp_help 'table_name'`

If there is any default constraint for that, delete that constraint and try adding the constraint.